# Error correcting algorithm for very strange data channel

Tags: algorithm, error-correction

Please recommend an error correcting algorithm for using very strange data channel.

[image: Diagram]

The channel consists of two parts: Corrupter and Eraser.

Corrupter receives a word consisting of 10000 symbols in 3-symbol alphabet, say, {'a','b','c'}.
Corrupter changes each symbol with probability 10%.
Example:

```
Corrupter input:  abcaccbacbbaaacbcacbcababacb...
Corrupter output: abcaacbacbbaabcbcacbcababccb...
```

Eraser receives corrupter output and erases each symbol with probability 94%.
Eraser produces word of the same length in 4-symbol alphabet {'a','b','c','*'}.
Example:

```
Eraser input:  abcaacbacbbaabcbcacbcababccb...
Eraser output: *******a*****************c**...
```

So, on eraser output, approximately 6%*10000=600 symbols would not be erased, approximately 90%*600=540 of them would preserve their original values and approximately 60 would be corrupted.

**What encoding-decoding algorithm with error correction is best suited for this channel?**
What amount of useful data could be transmitted providing > 99.99% probability of successful decoding?
Is it possible to transmit 40 bytes of data through this channel?  (256^40 ~ 3^200)

Comment: @Dukeling - thank you for comment, but please explain how sequence alignment could be helpful here.

Comment: Oh, never mind, misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can at least analyze:

Break your 40 bytes up into 13 25-bit chunks (with some wastage so this bit can obviously be improved)

2^25 < 3^16 so you can encode the 25 bits into 16 a/b/c "trits" - again wastage means scope for improvement.

With 10,000 trits available you can give each of your 13 encoded byte triples 769 output trits. Pick (probably at random) 769 different linear (mod 3) functions on 16 trits - each function is specified by 16 trits and you take a vector dot product between those trits and the 16 input trits. This gives you your 769 output trits.

Decode by considering all possible (2^25) chunks and pick the one which matches most of the surviving trits. You have some hope of getting the right answer as long as there are at least 16 surviving trits, which I think excel is telling me via BINOMDIST() happens often enough that there is a pretty good chance that it will happen for all of the 13 25-bit chunks.

I have no idea what error rate you get from garbling but random linear codes have a pretty good reputation, even if this one has a short blocksize because of my brain-dead decoding technique. At worst you could try simulating the encoding transmission and decoding of 25-bit chunks and work it out from there. You can get a slightly more accurate lower bound on error rate than above if you pretend that the garbling stage erases as well and so recalculate with a slightly higher probability of erasure.

I think this might actually work in practice if you can afford the 2^25 guesses per 25-bit block to decode. OTOH if this is a question in a class my guess is you need to demonstrate your knowledge of some less ad-hoc techniques already discussed in your class.

Comment: Thank you for your idea.  I was thinking about 10000 linear equations with random coefficients, but your idea about splitting this huge matrix in smaller parts makes decoding feasible.  Unfortunately, this is not "a question in a class" - it is real project about special sort of large 2D barcodes.

Comment: This decoding method's only real advantage is that it can be analysed. My guess is that prototyping would show http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code with belief propagation to be better. See also Chapter 47 in http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/toc.html where it calls what may be belief propagation the sum-product algorithm. After random erasure a random low density code is a randomly chosen low density code - for a real project you could even buy the paper book!

Comment: Thank you very much.  It seems to be exactly what I need.  Now I need some time for studying.  :-)